# Error in using System.Drawing and SVG Lib in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, asp.net-core

I want to use the [Svg](http://svg.codeplex.com/) library in Asp.Net Core as follows.

```
 var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(filePath);
 var Image = new Bitmap(svgDoc.Draw());
```

But the following error occurs for svgDoc.Draw().

```
Reference to type 'Bitmap' claims it is defined in 'System.Drawing', but it could not be found  

cannot resolve constructor bitmap(System.Drawing), candidate are::
Bitmap(string) (in class Bitmap)
Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image) (in class Bitmap)
Bitmap(System.IO.Stream) (in class Bitmap)
```

Comment: Does the library support usage on .NET Core (there are still some APIs and NuGet packages which cannot be used with .NET Core)? My thinking is that it doesn't support .NET Core, as System.Drawing isn't fully supported on .NET Core.

Comment: Ah, `System.Drawing` is supported in .NET Core... sort of. Only the Primitives are supplied, so you might have some luck adding this NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Primitives/), but it might not contain everything that the library you are consuming requires.

Comment: I use the Primitives Lib, But the error still occurs @jamie-taylor

Comment: You might need to use the Compatibility library to get some of the APIs you need from System.Drawing (https://github.com/CoreCompat/System.Drawing). I'd ask whether the application needs to use .NET Core, however. The library you have chosen seems to require APIs that .NET Core doesn't support (at the moment), it would be far easier to use full .NET Framework if you can.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution.
I convert svg to image through a .NET Framework Web service

Comment: @Shaw An alternative method is to use nodejs in the asp.net core for convert svg to png
https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-node-services-in-aspnet-core/
There are many libraries for doing this in Nodejs